# How to read text files with Graphviz?

Tags: graphviz

For example, I have put the weights of the edges in the txt file below:

```
0 1 2
1 0 3
2 3 0
```

The desired result is:

```
{
    node0--node1[weight=1];
    node0--node2[weight=2];
    node1--node2[weight=3];  
}
```

Comment: Why not use a template language to generate the desired output? If not, then please give more information as to why you need to use Graphviz.

Comment: There 10k nodes, I want to know if they can cluster through their distance. 10000*10000/2 egdes file's size 2G, it is too big for graphviz.

Comment: Graphing 10K of anything will produce a jumbled mess of lines and shapes that is, for all practical purposes, useless. You may want to consider partitioning your dataset.

Answer (score 0):

Graphviz understands text files with [DOT](https://graphviz.org/doc/info/lang.html) language, not [DSV](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Delimiter-separated_values)-like formats as in your example.

So you need to convert your file to DOT notation and that's a topic for a another question, but as a proof of concept and illustration of the fact (as mentioned in the comments to your question) that Graphviz may not be the best solution for visualization 50 000 000 edges in one image (you can ask app for clustering on the [Software Recommendations](https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com) website), I will show an example of generating a text file with random weights for ~20 000 edges between 200 nodes, then reading that file and converting it to DOT language (by [graphviz 0.19.1](https://pypi.org/project/graphviz/) package) and producing output [`.dot/.gv`](https://graphviz.org/docs/outputs/canon/#dot--gv), [`.canon`](https://graphviz.org/docs/outputs/canon/#canon) or `.png` file formats. The program was executed within 5 minutes.
Python 3.9.1 script:

```py
import graphviz as gv
import random

# Count of nodes:
size = 200
# Range of edges weights (upper limit):
weights_range = 10


# Generate txt file with random weights:
arr = [['0' for x in range(size)] for y in range(size)]
col = 1
for row in range (0, size):
    i = col
    while i < size:
        arr[row][i] = str(random.randrange(weights_range))
        arr[i][row] = arr[row][i]
        i+=1
    col+=1
with open('data.txt', 'w+') as file:
    for row in range(0, len(arr)):
        file.write(' '.join(arr[row]) +'\n')


# Create empty graph object:
Gr = gv.Graph(format='canon', # For PNG output change to 'png'.
              filename='graph.gv',
              engine='neato', # Layout engine.
              graph_attr=dict(splines='true',
                              sep='5',
                              overlap='scale'),
              node_attr=dict(shape='circle',
                             margin='0',
                             fontsize='10',
                             width='0.2',
                             height='0.2',
                             fixedsize='true'),
              edge_attr=dict(arrowsize='0.4'))


# Read data from file and add nodes/edges to graph object:
file = open('data.txt', 'r')
row = 0
col_shift = 1 # To shift the beginning of each line to the right,
# so as not to go over the diagonal line of zeros.
for line in file:
    line = line.strip()
    if len(line) == 0:
        continue
    weights = line.split(' ')
    col=col_shift
    while col < len(weights):
        # Variant 1. Long names for nodes:
        # Gr.edge('node'+str(row),'node'+str(col),weight=weights[col])
        # Variant 2. Short names for nodes:
        Gr.edge(str(row),str(col),weight=weights[col])
        col+=1
    row+=1
    col_shift+=1
file.close()

Gr.render() # Rendering graph to text file or image.
```

Result `.canon` (19 916 lines, ~500 KB) (I replaced the node-naming `node42` output with `42` to reduce the file size):

```
graph {
    graph [overlap=scale,
        sep=5,
        splines=true
    ];
    node [fixedsize=true,
        fontsize=10,
        height=0.2,
        label="\N",
        margin=0,
        shape=circle,
        width=0.2
    ];
    edge [arrowsize=0.4];
    0 -- 1  [weight=8];
    0 -- 2  [weight=1];
    0 -- 3  [weight=5];
    0 -- 4  [weight=2];
    0 -- 5  [weight=7];
...
    196 -- 198  [weight=0];
    196 -- 199  [weight=3];
    197 -- 198  [weight=0];
    197 -- 199  [weight=5];
    198 -- 199  [weight=9];
}
```

Result PNG (~20 000 edges between 200 nodes, ~5 MB):
[image: graph with 200 nodes and 20000 edges made with graphviz]

**P.S.** However, if you want to create such an image, the following questions may help you properly adjust graph settings for faster rendering and clear picture (these are optional and not exactly related to current question, so I don't want SO to auto-link them to current question, so I give their numbers instead of links):

- GraphViz Dot very long duration of generation
  `/questions/10766100`
- laying out a large graph with graphviz
  `/questions/13417411`
- Graphviz is too slow
  `/questions/64130276`
- Is it possible to generate a small GraphViz chart?
  `/questions/68321537`
- Compacting a digraph in Graphviz using Dot Language
  `/questions/8610710`
- Reducing the size (as in area) of the graph generated by graphviz
  `/questions/3428448`